# Svelte error on using function in class of html

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I have a li tag with a title which does the following:

```
          <li
        title={`Click to ${values.videos.length > 0 && values.videos.find(videoID => videoID == video.id.videoId) ? 'un' : ''}select`}
```

This works perfectly fine. But if I do the same in the class property:

```
          <li
        title={`Click to ${values.videos.length > 0 && values.videos.find(videoID => videoID == video.id.videoId) ? 'un' : ''}select`}
        class={`empty-button ${values.videos.length > 0 && values.videos.find(videoID => videoID == video.id.videoId) ? 'selected' : ''}`}
```

Then I get this error:
    [!] (plugin svelte) TypeError: Cannot set property 'maintain_context' of undefined

I don't really get why this happens. It seems to be a result of using the find method, as the error disappears when I remove the function. But it works in the title property, so it can't be the fault of the function.

Anybody an idea what is going on here?

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug. Can you create a reproduction in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl) and raise an issue please? Thanks

Comment: Will do tomorrow

Comment: I tried to create a reproduction of the bug, but I get an error when trying to add a style: TypeError: block is undefined

https://svelte.dev/repl/657de08ef06b42fda99c028489321890?version=3.14.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Svelte you use a a class directive. More [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#class_name).
When the expression becomes true the selected class will be added. Or removed if false.

```
<li class="empty-button" ... 
class:selected={values.videos.length > 0 && values.videos.find(videoID => videoID == video.id.videoI)} ...>
```